# How many ways to split 5 numbers in 2 groups?

Tags: factorial

How many ways can you split the numbers 1 to 5 into two groups of varying size?
For example: '1 and 2,3,4,5' or '1,2 and 3,4,5' or '1,2,3 and 4,5'. How many combinations are there like this? What is the formula?

Comment: Does the order of the two groups matter, are $(\{1,2\},\{3,4,5\})$ and $(\{3,4,5\},\{1,2\})$ counted as two splittings or just one? Can a group be empty?

Comment: Does the size of the groups have to sum up to $5$? Is there a limit to the size of each group? Since you have a repeat of $4$ in one of your examples, it doesn't look like you're "splitting" the $5$ numbers into groups.

Comment: @DanielFischer that would count as 1 splitting. And no group can be empty.

Comment: @Ataraxia they don't need to add to 5. I just used the numbers 1 to 5 for simplicity. The repeated 4 was a mistake, I have corrected this.

Comment: Probably just under half the binomial co-efficients would be my thinking as you only need to get up to half the elements before you are double counting things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great question.  It seems to me that there are two decisions that should be made.  The first is to determine the size of the two groups.  After that decision has been made, we must then decide which elements will go in which groups.

Suppose we split the $5$ numbers into a group of size $1$ and a group of size $4$.  How many ways can we do this?  Well, it suffices to just choose which number will be alone, so there are $5$ ways.

Next, let's split the numbers into a group of size $2$ and a group of size $3$.  How many ways can we do this?  Again, it suffices to choose the numbers for the smaller group.  Using a binomial coefficient, we find there are $\binom{5}{2}=10$ ways to do this.

Altogether, you will find $15$ ways.

See if you can show with $n$ elements there are $2^{n-1}-1$ ways to split into two smaller groups.

Comment: Doesn't this lead to double counting of some groups?  For example, in determining the number of size 2 groups this also counts the size 3 groups as it is the same set, no?

Comment: Thank you! Would I be correct in assuming that to split n items into 3 groups it would be 3^n-1 -1?

Comment: @JBKing: That is a good thing to look out for.  Notice that I have considered the case of groups of size $2$ and $3$ as one case, and once I determine the elements in the group of size $2$, those for the group of size $3$ are determined.  This is why I didn't pay attention to the group of size $3$.  You should find that there is no double counting here.

Comment: True, looking at the other answer I can see how the $2^{n-1}-1$ solution works as that is where I suspected there may be double counting though it isn't the case.

Comment: @user2679447:Close.  There is a bit more subtlety with three groups.  The answer is $$\frac{3^{n-1}-2^n+1}{2}$$

Comment: Hello. Thanks again, what if I had 20 items that I needed to split into 19 groups. I know it seems childish on my part, what if, what if, what if but potentially I might need to iterate 19 groups of 20 items. Would it be something like: $$\frac{20^{n-1}-19^n+1}{2}$$?

Comment: @user2679447, if you need to split $20$ items into $19$ *non-empty* groups, then one of the groups will contain two items and all the others just one, so it's just a question of choosing which $2$ of the $20$ items to go into the "distinguished" group of two, hence there are ${20\choose2} = {20\cdot19\over2}=190$ ways.

Comment: although this is a bit old thread, but I would add that using a simple binomial is not sufficient, ex: split $4$ into groups of $2$, according to your way it is $\binom{4}{2}=6$ which is an obvious wrong answer since there are duplicate among those possible $6$ ways, the right answer is $3$ ways (did it just using my pen)

Answer (score 2):

This is a basic application of the famous "Stirling Numbers of the second kind".

In case of $n$-subset-$2$, the formula is given by $2^{n-1} - 1$.

So, here, we get the answer to be $2^{5-1} - 1$, i.e. $15$.

Comment: Please use MathJax to format.

Answer (score 1):

The OP has specified that the order of the groups in the splitting doesn't matter, and also that the two groups must both be non-empty.  One of the groups must have the $1$, and that group either has or doesn't have each of the other four numbers, except that it can't have all four (which would leave the other group empty), so there are in total $2^4-1=15$ splittings.

Comment: Why the minus 1?

Comment: @user2679447, the $2^4$ includes the case where the other four numbers all go with the $1$, so you subtract $1$ to exclude that case.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of looking at the problem of splitting the numbers into group A and group B:

For every number, there are two choices: into group A or group B. If there are n numbers, then there are $2^n$ combinations.

We know that the order of the groups isn't important. For example, using the numbers in the original question, A={1,2,3} and B={4,5} is the same as A={4,5} and B={1,2,3}. As such, each combination in $2^n$ has a duplicate. Thus, $\frac{2^n}{2}$ or $2^{n-1}$.

There is one case where a group is empty. Since groups must be non-empty, we subtract this one case. Thus, $2^{n-1}-1$.